# c# форма с gaussian blur background как в iOS

Tags: c#, form, blur, sharpdx

Собственно, сама суть вопроса передана в заголовке.

Возможно ли сделать стандартными средствами форму с подобным эффектом?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @Lightness , Роли не играет. Нро предпочитаю WinForms если возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через Direct2d (C++):

```
ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> gaussianBlurEffect;
m_d2dContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1GaussianBlur, &gaussianBlurEffect);

gaussianBlurEffect->SetInput(0, bitmap);
gaussianBlurEffect->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, 3.0f);

m_d2dContext->BeginDraw();
m_d2dContext->DrawImage(gaussianBlurEffect.Get());
m_d2dContext->EndDraw();
```